# Encrypt in VB.NET With AES-256 and Decrypt in Air

Tags: vb.net, encryption, air, aes

I am trying to encrypt a zip in VB.NET to send to an android device using Air. Then once its on the device, decrypt it using the key and IV.

Here is part of my VB.NET Code:

```
     Private Sub EncryptBytes(ByVal fileIn As String, ByVal fileOut As String, ByVal pass As String, ByVal ivString As String)

        Dim crypt As New RijndaelManaged
        crypt.KeySize = 256
        crypt.BlockSize = 256
        crypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        crypt.Mode = CipherMode.CFB

        'read byte array from file location, ie c:\temp\file.zip
        Dim data As Byte() = ReadByteArray(fileIn)

        Dim iv As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivString)
        Dim key As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = crypt.CreateEncryptor(key, iv)

        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream

            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

                cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                cs.FlushFinalBlock()

            End Using

            'write byte array to file location, ie c:\temp\file_e.zip
            WriteByteArray(fileOut, ms.ToArray)

        End Using

    End Sub
```

Two things, first I don't want to use PaddingMode.PKCS7 but when I change it to PaddingMode.None I get an error which says "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid" during decryption.

Second, I have a decryption SUB and it still works if I send it a bogus IV. Why is the IV not effecting the decryption process.

#### DECRYPTION

In Air I'm using the com.hurlant.crypto package I found at http://crypto.hurlant.com/docs/.

Here is my function:

```
public static function decryptZip(src:ByteArray, k:String, iv:String):ByteArray {

    var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(k)); 

    var mode:CFBMode = new CFBMode(new AESKey(key), new PKCS7(256));
    mode.IV = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(iv));

    mode.decrypt(src);

    return src;

}
```

This is not working ... Note that I tried to write a PKCS7 class based on a Java class I found. The hurlant package I downloaded only had PKCS5. VB.NET did not provide any of the same padding classes as hurlant comes with. I wish I could using "None" but I couldn't get passed the error in VB.

I think there may also be an issue with the way I am converting a string into a byte array in VB vs Air.

Please help!

Comment: So after a day of struggling I found out my problem was that my BlockSize was 256 and thus my IV was 32. I made the BlockSize 128 and the IV 16 and now it works!!

Answer (score -2):

check out this sample code i am not sure if it's the solution you are looking for or not,
http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not having problems encrypting via VB.NET but the combination of VB.NET to Air.

Comment: oh i thought reverse but here it is http://www.newyyz.com/ntgsite/blog/?p=234 aesdecrypt example i hope it helps :)

Comment: Always add some code not just link to help future readers.